# JPG Image Processing

Tags: .net, image-processing, jpeg, resampling

Is it possible to disable 'Chroma Subsampling' during resampling or resizing a JPG image?

Disabling Chroma Subsampling is same as YCbCr filter 4x4x4 as far as I understand.

Is there a library for .NET which I can use to do it?

Thanks for reading friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it natively but there are libraries out there such as [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) that have options to [change the subsampling](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fnet/html/E77CD483.htm).

**EDIT**

Here's a sample with OR'd together flags:

```
    Using I = New FreeImageAPI.FreeImageBitmap("c:\input.jpg")
        I.Save("c:\output.jpg", FreeImageAPI.FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG, FreeImageAPI.FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_SUBSAMPLING_444 Or FreeImageAPI.FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_QUALITYSUPERB)
    End Using
```

Comment: FreeImage sucks. Just can't add the FreeImage.dll to my asp.net test project. The wrapper FreeImageNET.dll is referenced just fine.

Comment: Both of this dlls compiled just fine. How should I use the native dll in an asp.net project?

Comment: To use the wrapper you need to have the native FreeImage.dll side-by-side with it. For a web app you might be able to put it into the Bin folder but I haven't tried that. What always works for me is to put the native DLL into the System32 folder. There might be a way to merge these two files together, too (LINK.EXE) but I'm no expert at that.

Comment: i will try putting it into the system32 to see

Comment: FreeImage just can't create the quality I need. Plus you can't use multiple save flags in one save/saveEx call. I can use GDI+ for this type of quality.

Comment: @Projapati, what do you mean you can't use multiple flags? Can't you just OR them together?

Comment: How do you OR them? Do you have sample code? I want to use the quality flag and another flag for sampling in the same saveEx() command. I tried to put multiple options but is gives syntax error. Are you refering | type or?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a VB example of using multiple flags. The C# version would use the vertical pipe `|` instead of the `OR ` keyword.